# How to save image(Base64 String) in Ionic-Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4

I have a backend rest api deployed in azure.

```
Angular/Ionic App --> Rest call --> Rest API

Angular/Ionic App <--- image (base64 string) --- Rest API
```

**Scenario:** I am using this image (encoded as base64 string) in multiple pages in the application and I don't want to make a rest call multiple times.

Current implementation in ionic/angular:

```
export class LoginVerificationService {

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient,
            public router: Router,
            **@Inject(SESSION_STORAGE) private storage: StorageService,**
            private endpoints: EndpointsConstantsService
) {
}
//method that saves the values in session
setSession(userEmail: string,username:string, age:string, image: string) {
    this.storage.set(this.endpoints.SESSION_EMAIL, userEmail);
    this.storage.set(this.endpoints.SESSION_AGE, age);
    this.storage.set(this.endpoints.SESSION_IMAGE, image);
    this.storage.set(this.endpoints.SESSION_USERNAME, username);
}
```

I am able to save name and age but the app crashes when i try to save the base64 image. Is there any other way i can implement this?

Comment: Tell us the error it returns.

Comment: What do you mean by app crash? Share the error code

Comment: It worked later. I think the issue is initially when i tried to save the image the browser was unable to save the image(bas64) due to insufficient space. But I was able to save the image and its working fine now. Thankyou!